# How do I check a pair of values against only specific columns of a matrix?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a vector A = (34, 70) that I want to check is in a very large matrix (10700 by 3) such that 34 is in the first column, 70 is in the second, and they are "together" as in the same row. What complicates it, and what is stumping me, is that I need to do this for about 2000 pairs of numbers and then over 20 samples. What is the fastest way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

One option is `match`

```
match(asplit(m1[, 1:2], 1), asplit(a1, 1))
#[1]  1 NA NA  1  2 NA
```

#### data

```
m1 <- cbind(c(34, 23, 35, 34, 42, 49), c(70, 24, 32, 70, 43, 234), 25)
a1 <- cbind(c(34, 42), c(70, 43))
```